# .include in openssl.cnf file requires full path of the external file(fipsmodule.cnf) though both files are present in same directory

Tags: openssl, fips, cnf

```
root@7471dedf6387:# pwd
```

/tmp/test/lib/

```
root@7471dedf6387:# ls
```

fips.so  fipsmodule.cnf  libcrypto.so.3  openssl.cnf

Providing the full path of the fipsmodule.cnf file inside openssl.cnf WORKS!

> cat openssl.cnf

…..

.include /tmp/test/lib/fipsmodule.cnf

…..

Not providing the full path of the fipsmodule.cnf file inside openssl.cnf FAILS!!

> cat openssl.cnf

…..

.include fipsmodule.cnf

.....

So, how to include the “fipsmodule.cnf” file without providing the FULL path inside openssl.cnf file, when both files are present inside the same directory?

Comment: What does being in the same directory as the `openssl.cnf` file have to do with providing the process all the data necessary to locate the `fipsmodule.cnf` file?  If you live at "102 F Street" in your town and send a letter to just "100", where will your post office deliver it?